# Can someone explain to me why static sychonised code returns this result?

Tags: java, multithreading, oop, static

```
public class Threads9Main
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Threads9 thread1 = new Threads9("Thread1");
        Threads9 thread2 = new Threads9("Thread2");
        Threads9 thread3 = new Threads9("Thread3");
        Threads9 thread4 = new Threads9("Thread4");
        Threads9 thread5 = new Threads9("Thread5");
        Threads9 thread6 = new Threads9("Thread6");
        Threads9 thread7 = new Threads9("Thread7");
        Threads9 thread8 = new Threads9("Thread8");

        thread1.start();
        thread2.start();
        thread3.start();
        thread4.start();
        thread5.start();
        thread6.start();
        thread7.start();
        thread8.start();
    }
}

public class Threads9 extends Thread
{   

public Threads9(String paramName)
    {
        name = paramName;
    }
    private static String name;

    public void run() 
    {
        print();
    }

    private static synchronized void print() 
    {
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(name+ " looping");
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the 1st 5 lines of my outcome:

```
Thread8 looping
Thread8 looping
Thread8 looping
Thread8 looping
Thread8 looping
```

Why does it only show thread8 and not thread1-7?

Comment: Because it's a `static` field?

Comment: Note that java.lang.Thread already has a name property that you could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
private static String name;
```

This means that there is only one `name` field and it is `static`, that means that it is shared between all instances of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Static fields belong to class and are shared across all objects of that class. in your case

```
private static String name;
```

is a single shared field.
On each Thread creation it overwrites the prev value and before starting all Threads the value of a `name` is 'Thread8'. As a result you see that it prints `Thread8` all the time.